# how to replace everything except string of interest

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

**file.txt**

```
fruits:banana,apple,grape,limon,orange,tomate,
fruits:apple,limon,
fruits:banana,grape,limon,
fruits:orange,tomate,grape,
fruits:banana,
fruits:apple,
fruits:banana,apple,
```

I need to replace everything that is different than "banana" for FRUIT, and get output like this:

```
fruits:banana,FRUIT,FRUIT,FRUIT,FRUIT,FRUIT,
fruits:FRUIT,FRUIT,
fruits:banana,FRUIT,FRUIT,
fruits:FRUIT,FRUIT,FRUIT,
fruits:banana,
fruits:FRUIT,
fruits:FRUIT,apple,
```

I tried using awk, but I can only replace the fields of specific strings.

Example replace all strings "apple" by fruit2, or all strings "apple" by fruit2 and all strings "tomate"or "orange" by fruit3

```
awk -F":" '{ gsub(/apple/,"FRUIT2",$2); print }' OFS="," file.tx
```

or

```
awk -F":" '{ gsub(/apple/,"FRUIT2",$2);;gsub(/tomate|orange/,"FRUIT3",$2); print }' OFS="," file.txt |sed "s/./:/7"

fruits:banana,FRUIT2,grape,limon,FRUIT3,FRUIT3,
fruits:FRUIT2,limon,
fruits:banana,grape,limon,
fruits:FRUIT3,FRUIT3,grape,
fruits:banana,
fruits:FRUIT2,
fruits:banana,FRUIT2
```

but I really need is to replace everything that is different from that for any string, ex: fruit4

How to generate output like this?

```
fruits:FRUIT4,FRUIT2,FRUIT4,FRUIT4,FRUIT3,FRUIT3,
fruits:FRUIT2,FRUIT4,
fruits:FRUIT4,FRUIT4,FRUIT4,
fruits:FRUIT3,FRUIT3,FRUIT4,
fruits:FRUIT4,
fruits:FRUIT2,
fruits:FRUIT4,FRUIT2
```

Comment: Do you want the output to look like [this](https://regex101.com/r/kP1cS7/1)?

Comment: It's not clear if you want specific fruit names mapped to specific new values (apple=FRUIT39), or every new fruit name mapped to a new value based on some base with a numeric suffix (FRUIT1, FRUIT2, etc.) or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk should work:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
     if ($i !~ /(^|:)banana$/)
        sub(/[^:]+$/, "FRUIT", $i)
} 1' file
```

**Output:**

```
fruits:banana,FRUIT,FRUIT,FRUIT,FRUIT,FRUIT,
fruits:FRUIT,FRUIT,
fruits:banana,FRUIT,FRUIT,
fruits:FRUIT,FRUIT,FRUIT,
fruits:banana,
fruits:FRUIT,
fruits:banana,FRUIT,
```

Comment: This approach will fail with other fruits, e.g. if the target was apple instead of banana and the input file contained pineapple then pineapple wouldn't be converted to FRUIT. IMHO including the part before `:` in `$1` and so in the comparisons really isn't the right approach and so is causing unnecessary complexity and potential error cases to creep in.

Comment: Thanks Ed, yes a word boundary is needed to safeguard the search.

Comment: You're welcome. you should mention that'll make it gawk-specific. Oh and nit-pick - the gsub should just be a sub.

Comment: Thanks again, yes indeed `gsub` isn't needed. I also changed regex to `(^|:)` so that it is not gnu-awk specific.

Comment: Sounds good, now let's just hope the OP never has to deal with `Açai Berries` or similar that contain spaces, etc. :-).

Comment: Interesting, made another change to take care of fruit names with space. Hope a fruit name won't contain colon :-)

Answer (score 1):

To make the process automated, you can do

```
awk -F '[:,]' -v OFS=, '
    {
        for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) 
            if ($i)
                if (seen[$i])
                    $i = seen[$i]
                else 
                    $i = seen[$i] = "FRUIT" ++n
        sub(OFS, ":")
        print
    }
    END {
        print "map:"
        for (key in seen)
            print key "\t" seen[key]
    }
' file
```

```
fruits:FRUIT1,FRUIT2,FRUIT3,FRUIT4,FRUIT5,FRUIT6,
fruits:FRUIT2,FRUIT4,
fruits:FRUIT1,FRUIT3,FRUIT4,
fruits:FRUIT5,FRUIT6,FRUIT3,
fruits:FRUIT1,
fruits:FRUIT2,
fruits:FRUIT1,FRUIT2,
map:
orange  FRUIT5
tomate  FRUIT6
apple   FRUIT2
limon   FRUIT4
banana  FRUIT1
grape   FRUIT3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like some flexibility in being able to specify your mapping of old to new names on the command line:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS="[:,]"; OFS=","
    split(map,t)
    for (i=1; i in t; i+=2) {
        m[t[i]] = t[i+1]
    }
}
{
    printf "%s:", $1
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ($i in m )      { $i = m[$i] }
        else if ("*" in m) { $i = m["*"] }
        printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF?OFS:ORS)
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -v map='apple,FRUIT2,tomate,FRUIT3,*,FRUIT4' -f tst.awk file
fruits:FRUIT4,FRUIT2,FRUIT4,FRUIT4,FRUIT4,FRUIT3,FRUIT4
fruits:FRUIT2,FRUIT4,FRUIT4
fruits:FRUIT4,FRUIT4,FRUIT4,FRUIT4
fruits:FRUIT4,FRUIT3,FRUIT4,FRUIT4
fruits:FRUIT4,FRUIT4
fruits:FRUIT2,FRUIT4
fruits:FRUIT4,FRUIT2,FRUIT4

$ awk -v map='apple,BAZINGA,*,VEGGIE' -f tst.awk file
fruits:VEGGIE,BAZINGA,VEGGIE,VEGGIE,VEGGIE,VEGGIE,VEGGIE
fruits:BAZINGA,VEGGIE,VEGGIE
fruits:VEGGIE,VEGGIE,VEGGIE,VEGGIE
fruits:VEGGIE,VEGGIE,VEGGIE,VEGGIE
fruits:VEGGIE,VEGGIE
fruits:BAZINGA,VEGGIE
fruits:VEGGIE,BAZINGA,VEGGIE

$ awk -v map='apple,FRUIT2,tomate,FRUIT3' -f tst.awk file
fruits:banana,FRUIT2,grape,limon,orange,FRUIT3,
fruits:FRUIT2,limon,
fruits:banana,grape,limon,
fruits:orange,FRUIT3,grape,
fruits:banana,
fruits:FRUIT2,
fruits:banana,FRUIT2,
```